# AWS API General Template - had to remove dashes from general template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I picked the `Method Request passthrough` for the general template under `method integration`.

```
"context" : {
    "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
    "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
    "api-key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
    "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId",
    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
    "httpmethod" : "$context.httpMethod",
```

I had to take the dash out of httpmethod for the lambda to see it (I also had to changed `body-json`). But if I test using API Gateway console tester, it shows the values as-is with dashes and all.

So the lambda inline code looks like the following:

```
            method: event.context.httpmethod,
        }
    })
};
return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Its worth using `Lambda proxy integration` on the API Gateway.

2.With the Lambda proxy integration, when a client submits an API request, API Gateway passes to the integrated Lambda function the raw request as-is. This request data includes the request headers, query string parameters, URL path variables, payload, and API configuration data. The configuration data can include current deployment stage name, stage variables, user identity, or authorization context (if any). The backend Lambda function parses the incoming request data to determine the response that it returns.
[image]
3. [aws lambda proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy)

Hope that helps